# Symlink to HTTP URL

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3, cdn, symlink

I am basically trying to move most of my static images to an Amazon S3 bucket but my site still needs to look for the originals through the filesystem in order to generate thumbnails.

```
/home/user/public_html/upload/2015/*.gif to http://s3.amazonbucketurl/upload/2015/*.gif
```

I read symlinks can't direct to http. What options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

The *correct* solution is to modify your application to load what it needs from S3 directly, because you are correct -- symlinks cannot natively reference http destinations.

The *work-around* is to use a mechanism like [`s3fs`](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) which gives the *illusion* that your S3 bucket is a mounted filesystem on your server... which you can symlink to.

This is not a genuine and proper solution, because S3 is not really a filesystem (it's an object store) and thus does not precisely follow filesystem semantics.  You will not see the same performance you expect from a local filesystem or from accessing S3 directly, natively in your code, because s3fs (of necessity) has extra work to do to try to bridge the impedance gap between "filesystem" and "object store."  It does an admirable job, but it is trying to accomplish a task that is conceptually impossible to execute perfectly.

There's no magic bullet solution.